# same response different routes in express.js using regex

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I need to create two URLs that sends same response.

```
app.get('/:city', sendCityResponse);
app.get('/:city/filters', sendCityResponse);
```

How can i make it as one route using regex?

I tried this:

```
app.get('/:city/:type(filters|^$)')
```

but with no success.

Comment: pattern should be enclosed within `//` forward slahes.

Comment: @AvinashRaj that works but i will not get the city value in that case.

Comment: @Unihedron it works when i use like this:
app.get('/:city([^-/]+)(?:/filters)?', sendCityResponse);

Comment: you could try this also, `/:city(?:/filters)?`

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

`app.get('/:city/:filter?', sendCityResponse);`